# Magento 2 item data is gone after update custom option value

Tags: magento2, custom-options, quoteitem

i have an additional data in my item cart which can be seen with $item->getData():

```
[item_id] => 319
[quote_id] => 122
[created_at] => 2017-09-29 02:35:42
[updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[product_id] => 9
[store_id] => 4
......
[test] => 4
```

The problem is when i update my custom option value programmatically like this:

```
$buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();
$currentOptions = $buyRequest->getOptions();

if ($currentOptions) {
    foreach ($currentOptions as $currentOptionId => $currentOptionValue) {
        if (empty($currentOptionValue)) continue;
            switch ($currentOptionId) {
                case $commentOptionId:
                    $newOptions[$currentOptionId] = ($updateComment)
                    ? $info[$item->getId()]['comment'] : $currentOptionValue;
                    break;
                case $requestshippingdateOptionId:
                    $newOptions[$currentOptionId] = ($updateRequestshippingdate)
                    ? $convertedDate : $currentOptionValue;
                    break;
                default:
                    $newOptions[$currentOptionId] = $currentOptionValue;
                    break;
            }
    }
}
$quote->updateItem($item->getId(), $buyRequest);
```

When i print the $item->getData() again, the item id is different and my additional data is gone.

```
[item_id] => 322
[quote_id] => 122
[created_at] => 2017-09-29 02:38:45
[updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[product_id] => 9
[store_id] => 4
...
[test] =>
```